# Add custom message to attribute validation in extended modal in yii2

Tags: validation, yii2, customization, message

I have one modal class in yii2 with rules defined as

```
return [
            [['charity_name', 'address', 'contact_name', 'title', 'dialling_code', 'phone_no', 'email', 'notes', 'added_by', 'created_at'], 'required'],
            [['dialling_code', 'phone_no', 'added_by', 'created_at', 'status'], 'integer'],
            [['charity_name', 'contact_name', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['address', 'title'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
            [['notes'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
            [['charity_name'], 'unique'],
            [['added_by'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => Users::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['added_by' => 'id']],
            [['dialling_code'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => CountryDiallingCodes::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['dialling_code' => 'id']],
        ];
```

I want to show message for as "Phone number should be numeric" so I put the below function in extended class as

```
  public function rules() {
      $rules = parent::rules();
      $rules[] = [['phone_no'], 'integer', ['message'=>'Phone number should be numeric']];
      return $rules;
   }
```

But it does not seems to be working .. Please let me know how can I add custom message for attribute in extended modal class

Comment: `$rules[] = [['phone_no'], 'integer', 'message'=>'Phone number should be numeric'];`

Comment: HI @AlwaysLearn: Atleast reply t the answer given below. Whether it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function rules() {
    $rules = parent::rules();
    $rules[] = [['phone_no'], 'integer', 'message'=>'Phone number should be numeric'];
    return $rules;
}
```

Remove `[]` from `message`.

You can Add `pattern` too for validating.

```
$rules[] = [['mobile_no'], 'match', 'pattern'=>"/^\d{10}$/", 'message'=>'Phone number should be numeric'];
```